# environment variables for firebase when hosting flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am hosting flutter web app on firebase.
How do I pass env (non secret) variables to firebase?
I deploy with `firebase deploy` command.

When running flutter locally, I pass env variable as a flag in command line argument:

`flutter run --dart-define=envFileName=local.env --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security"`

Answer (score 2):

I just spent all day figuring this out. I was trying to get Github actions working. So the official docs say to use 'source' in your firebase.json file. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/flutter What isn't clear is that when you have source in the config, it will build the flutter app when you run
`firebase deploy`. That clears out any build parameters you sent in previously, even if you just built with `--dart-define` parameters.

The solution is to change your firebase.conf file to something like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    },
    "rewrites": [ {
   "source": "**",
   "destination": "/index.html"
} ]
  }
}
```

Then build your app

`flutter build --dart-define=envFileName=local.env`

Then deploy

`firebase deploy`

Comment: This was really helpful! 

`flutter build web --dart-define=envFileName=local.env`
Needed to add `web` there.

In my local setup, I was editing `firebase.json` rather than `firebase.conf`. I had `"source": "."`, which I replaced with `"public": "build/web",`. The `rewrites` section is not in my `firebase.json`.

Comment: @andersan 
thank you, your comment really helped me 
searching for this is like digging for treasure.